# Velocity of the photon

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, velocity, vectors

As far as I know photon travels in a wave pattern, that means it has $x$ and $y$ axis velocity components. If photon travels along $x$ axis, then what is it's maximum $y$ axis velocity?

Comment: If a photon travels in the x axis, it has no y axis velocity. And what you say about the wave pattern, a wave needs not to travel in two directions.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're getting mixed up with propagation of waves in a physical medium like a string. If you have a wave travelling on a string then it has a velocity along the string, but the string is also oscillating normal to its length. So if you stretched the string along the $z$ axis, as the wave travelled along the string (i.e. the $z$ axis) the string would be oscillating in the $x$ or $y$ directions.

Propagation of an electromagnetic wave is entirely different. There is no sense that anything is moving normal to the direction of travel. What happens is that the electric field at a point on the $z$ axis increases and decreases again in a direction normal to the $z$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the process of quantization with the wave-nature of propagating electromagnetic fields.

When you look at a Electromagnetic waves as photons, this means you don't look at their wave-characteristics, and you consider them as particles travelling with the speed of light, and those particle could "hit" electrons and knock them our of the atom like what happens in the [Compton effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).

The quantization of electromagnetic waves into photons takes full chunks of the electromagnetic waves (their energy, basically) and splits them into *quanta*, or into "countable pieces". It's more or less like taking a teapot, and pouring tea into 5 cups. The tea itself is liquid, but the whole cup of tea isn't a liquid, and cups of tea can be counted. (This is just a rough approximation so that you won't confuse electromagnetic field with quantized photons, reality is a little bit more complicated, like in the [double-slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A photon is the quantized unit of the electromagnetic field. If you have en electromagnetic wave propagating in the x-direction, this must consist of a magnetic field and an electric field oscillating perpendicularly to the direction of travel, and to each other, i.e. in the y and z directions.

If you have a wave with a frequency of, as an example, 50Hz, it completes a cycle in 1/50 = 0.02s. Being a sine wave, the oscillation traverses 2pi radians. So the angular velocity of the wave would be v = d/t = 2pi rads/0.02s = ~314 rads/s